# Refused entry to Spain previously. Will this affect my Student visa application?

Tags: schengen, study, student-visa, spain, pakistani-citizen

I am from Pakistan and applied for a Schengen tourist visa for Spain in 2013. The visa was rejected on the grounds the purpose of visit wasn’t clear and that they couldn’t determine whether I would return to my own country, plus that my funds weren’t enough for a visit of two weeks. I had all the documentation that one could think of, from the invitation letter from a local Spanish resident to the hotel booking, sufficient bank balance ($12,000 for two weeks) and much more. I appealed the decision instantly and provided them with the invitation letter and still got a refusal stating that my intentions of returning back to my country were not clear. Understandably, I was 23 at that time and I can comprehend their stereotyping process and what not.

Now I will be reapplying for a Student Schengen visa for my master's at a reputable university in Spain, for which I have a 30% scholarship.

Will my earlier rejection affect my Student visa?

My parents will be sponsoring my tuition and living costs. How can I make clear that I am only going for educational purposes and will return to my country?

I do not have dependents nor any immovable property in Pakistan. Although I can fork around a reasonable bank balance from my parents and on my own ($65-70k) and my total cost of tuition and cost of living shall be $30k. Would the chances still be lower? I can ask my current employer to make me a job offer when I have completed my masters. Any suggestions on how to further improve my chances?

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if the earlier refusal was really because they were questioning the source of your funding. You say you can 'fork' money around from other accounts to your own. That kind of behavior is exactly the kind of thing case workers are looking out for as it makes it appear that you merely shuffling money around to qualify for entry that you truly may not qualify for.

Comment: Sorry it's a late comment, but please restrict posts to one question per post, as per the [help]. Thanks!